# Zero Bytes Files are getting created by ADF data flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There is a Conditional Split in my ADF data flow. Success puts the rows to a SQL database and failure conditions collect all the incorrect records and puts them into a sink which is of type CSV (Delimited text).

[image]

In case of success condition, there is an empty CSV file of 0 bytes is getting created in the sink.

How can I stop this?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can. A branch is not an IF statement, so the branch exists whether or not any rows are fed to it, so the Sink will still run. In the case of Storage sinks, that means a 0 byte blob will get created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to write output to an external source, you can use **cache sink**. It writes data into the Spark cache instead of a data store. In mapping data flows, you can reference this data within the same flow many times using a cache lookup. If you want to store this later to a data store, just reference data as part of an expression.

To write to a cache sink, add a sink transformation and select Cache as the sink type. Unlike other sink types, you don't need to select a dataset or linked service because you aren't writing to an external store.

[image]

> **Note:** A cache sink must be in a completely independent data stream from any transformation referencing it via a cache lookup. A cache
> sink also must the first sink written.
>
> When utilizing cached lookups, make sure that your sink ordering has
> the cached sinks set to 1, the lowest (or first) in ordering.

[image]

Reference this data within the same flow using a cache lookup, as part of an expression to store this to a data store.

[image]

[image]

Alternately use cache lookup against source to select and write it to CSV or log in a different stream or sink.

[image]

Refer: [CacheSink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-sink#cache-sink), [CachedLookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#cached-lookup)

If you still want to delete empty Zero byte files, you can use ADF or programmatic way to delete at the end of execution (**Delete Activity in Azure Data Factory**)

[Examples of using the Delete activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/delete-activity#examples-of-using-the-delete-activity)